# Where to find the whole log of a maintenance plan package job that failed with error?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent, log, maintenance-plans

I have a maintenance plan that runs on SQL Server agent as a the job and finishes with error. However the error is not visible in job history in SSMS, the text of **Message** is seemingly truncated. How can I see the whole log and which command actually failed?

```
Date        22.08.2020 23:00:00
Log     Job History (MP - HeliosG Optimizations.Subplan_1)

Step ID     1
Server      XXXX
Job Name        MP - HeliosG Optimizations.Subplan_1
Step Name       Subplan_1
Duration        02:26:43
Sql Severity    0
Sql Message ID  0
Operator Emailed    
Operator Net sent   
Operator Paged  
Retries Attempted   0

Message
Executed as user: XXXX\SYSTEM. ...ion 10.0.6000.29 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  23:00:00  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:01.35     Source: {4DF475B9-8D88-4BD3-9AFC-48FBBDAC9EB9}      Executing query "DECLARE @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:11.26     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 0% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:14.47     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_AnalyzaDL]   WITH FULLSC...".: 1% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:14.47     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 1% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:16.34     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_AnalyzaDL_Historie]   WI...".: 2% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:16.34     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 2% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:16.68     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_CenPodm]   WITH FULLSCAN...".: 3% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:16.68     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 3% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:16.99     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_CenPodmSmlouvy]   WITH F...".: 4% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.00     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 4% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.01     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_Dodavatele]   WITH FULLS...".: 5% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.01     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 6% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.12     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_DopPodmSmlouvy]   WITH F...".: 6% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.12     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 7% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.17     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_DopravniPodm]   WITH FUL...".: 7% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.17     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 8% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.22     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_DoPTEST]   WITH FULLSCAN...".: 8% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.22     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 9% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.23     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_FBL3N]   WITH FULLSCAN  ".: 9% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.23     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 10% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.29     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_IK17]   WITH FULLSCAN  ".: 10% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.29     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 11% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.31     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_KatBeda]   WITH FULLSCAN...".: 12% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.31     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "use [EkDB]  ".: 12% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.40     Source: Update Statistics      Executing query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[_MB51]   WITH FULLSCAN  ".: 13% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2020-08-22 23:00:17.40     Source: ...  The package execution fa...  The step failed.
```

Comment: @vojtech, not the answer but a recommendation, use ola's script for updating the statistics [here](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could try logging the out put in the advanced tab for the job step, there are couple of options 1) log to a table in msdb 2) log the output to a file

[image: job_step_advanced]